# Alternatives to Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a computer with Windows 8 Enterprise (Evaluation) and an Intel Q8300 CPU (which does not support SLAT as far as I know).

I also own a Samsung ATIV S - Windows Phone 8 smartphone.

I would like to develop Windows Phone 8 app(s) but the emulator won't run on my PC. What are my options? Can I plug the phone via the USB cable and debug the app on it? Or this will also require a developer account (which I hear is 100 US dollars per year)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to unlock your phone to debug applications on it, and **yes**, you need a Windows Phone Developer account to do that. It costs 100$ per year.

MSDN: [About deploying and running apps on a Windows Phone device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_device)

> You have to meet the following prerequisites before you can deploy an
>   app to a Windows Phone device:
>
> - You **must be a registered developer**. For info about registering as a developer, see [Registration info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206719%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
> - The **phone must be registered**. For more info, see [How to register your phone for development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

And about Dev Account cost: [Register for a Dev Center account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206719%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> An **annual Dev Center subscription is $99 USD** plus any applicable tax.
>   For that, you’ll get to submit unlimited paid apps to Windows Phone
>   Store. You can also submit up to 100 free apps.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pay for Windows Phone Developer account. All you need is a computer with Zune software running and a USB cable. The rest is mostly automated.

Comment: Are you sure this is true for Windows Phone 8? Zune sounds like Windows Phone 7.x...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your app, if you can get 99% working on f.e. android, it might be an option to upload a winphone build to the Windows Phone Store and specify its a *beta* submission. To do this, yes, you need a developer account. But you dont need to unlock your phone.

Add yourself (and other devs) to the beta tester list and submit the app.
It will be available in ~1 hour, but it doesnt really appear in the store; you need to install it using a link sent to you by mail.

As for debugging, try Weinre.